# How to add string array to okhttp body

Tags: java, okhttp

I'm trying to add String[] to okhttp body.
The resulting json should be like this:

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "passwords": [
        "asd123123",
        "sdf123232"
    ]
}
```

I do not know how many passwords there would be before I receive them.

My code:

```
public String getArrToString(String[] arrayData) {
          StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

          for (int i = 0 ; i < arrayData.length; i++) {
            stringBuilder.append(arrayData[i]);
            if (i < arrayData.length - 1) {
                stringBuilder.append(",");
            }
          }

          return stringBuilder.toString();
        }
```

and

```
String arrayData[] = user.getPasswords();    
body = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("name", user.getName())    
                .addFormDataPart("passwords", getArrToString(arrayData))
                .build();
```